# .NET 5 - Json Serialization with comma as decimal separator

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, .net-5

Is there a way to serialize a JsonResult in a controller considering the current locale?
In my case when the language is set to italian I wish separator for decimal values was ',' instead of '.'.

`JsonDataTable<SomeObj> res = new JsonDataTable<SomeObj>(someObjList);`

`return new JsonResult(res);`

Comment: But then the document will no longer be valid JSON! Or, rather, it would be, but `[0.123]` is semantically different from `[0, 123]`. I suppose you could store the decimal numbers as strings (`["0,123"]`), but I think it's more likely that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (i.e. you're asking about a potential solution rather than the underlying problem that would necessitate such a solution).

Comment: Don't try that. The numeric format in JSON is well defined and part of the standard. *Nobody* will be able to understand that JSON string if you try to use localized values. Besides, how could any parser differentiate between decimals and array items if you actually did what you want?

Comment: Why are you asking for this? If you want to display numbers a certain way, you need to do that on the client. Browsers already know the user's preferred language from the user's settings. Some HTML elements use this to display eg date and numeric data. In other cases you can generate localized strings with explicit calls

Comment: Json is just a universal way to store information, so it should not know anything about languages. When you DISPLAY the values, you should localize them (that's the same as in C# you must use dot as decimal separator, but when displaying you can format it to any culture).

Comment: I totally get your point, and eventually I managed to handle the issue on the client. But what if I wanted to serialize all decimals as strings with the comma separator?

Comment: The easiest way is to make the property a string (converting the number to string, when setting), then it would of course get saved as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example of culture-specific decimal converter - copied from [here](https://makolyte.com/csharp-deserializing-json-with-quoted-numbers/):

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class CultureSpecificQuotedDecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetString(),   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"));
        }
        else
        {
            return reader.GetInt32();
        }
    }

    //Write() not shown
}
```

Use like this:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jsonOptions.Converters.Add(new CultureSpecificQuotedDecimalConverter());

var movie = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Movie>(movieJson, jsonOptions);

Console.WriteLine($"Year={movie.YearReleased} Revenue={movie.Revenue}");
```

Comment: This is about deserialization, my question is about serialization.